# John Papa's Angular Style Guide Y165 Recommendation... what to inject in app.core module?

Tags: angularjs

In [Y165](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y165), John Papa recommends injecting cross app modules into app.core.

```
angular.module('app.core', [angular modules, 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', cross-app modules, 3rd party modules]);
```

However, in his other examples, he manually injects everything he needs in their own module... i.e.

```
dataservice.$inject = ['$http'];
```

$http is a common one, so I'm thinking about injecting it into app.core. Would that be a bad idea?

I'm a little confused, what exactly do I inject into app.core and how do I determine whether it should be injected manually or if it should be injected into app.core? (i.e. is there an unspoken rule like put it into app.core if 2+ modules share it? 3+ modules?)

Comment: $http is a service injection, not a module. You register modules  dependencies in app.core (angular-animate, angular-sanitize...), and inject services, factories... right where you need them, in your case, dataservice.

Comment: @tpsilva I see, looks like I got a bit confused about the definition of a module. In that case, John Papa also has a "common" factory on app.core module where he recommends I inject common dependencies like $q, $broadcast. Is that where I should inject $http then, assuming it's used in more than one module?

Comment: You are still confused, read [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) ($http) and [modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) (ngAnimate)